# python program not running with conda env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, environment

My program was running fine in VSC when I first set up the anaconda environment but now its not doing anything. The default shell was python powershell but that wouldnt active the conda env so I changed it to bash and now its automatically activating the right environment but the program isnt running. My path to conda env is set in VSC  settings and default env is set to the correct one.

```
(base)
alexa@LAPTOP-FS9J MINGW64 ~/C Dropbox/user name/gprobs/tiftolake
$ C:/Users/alexa/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
(base) 
alexa@LAPTOP-FS9J MINGW64 ~/C Dropbox/user name/gprobs/tiftolake
$ conda activate conda_env
(conda_env) 
alexa@LAPTOP-FS9J MINGW64 ~/C Dropbox/user name/gprobs/tiftolake
$ C:/Users/alexa/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/python.exe "c:/Users/alexa/C Dropbox/user name/gprobs/tiftolake/gprobs.py"
(conda_env) 
alexa@LAPTOP-FS9J MINGW64 ~/C Dropbox/user name/gprobs/tiftolake
```

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? Can you show it?

Comment: It looks like your python script without any output, Could you simple add `print("test")` in your python file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.